# Setting multiple options in /etc/default/keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

Here is my `/etc/default/keyboard` file. The `XKBOPTIONS` is only setting the last option (map left control to meta) but not the first. How do I set multiple `XKBOPTIONS`? Thanks.

Extra info: Corresponding bash command for what I would like (but does not persist between restarts): `setxkbmap -option caps:ctrl_modifier -option ctrl:lctrl_meta`

---

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE
# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="gb"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS="caps:ctrl_modifier,ctrl:lctrl_meta"

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

Comment: Possibly there is a `gsettings` value which overrides `/etc/default/keyboard`. To find out, try the command: `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options`

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson - yes, this showed up ['ctrl:lctrl_meta'], I have reset the xkb-options and will see how this goes

Answer (score 2):

The solution in my case was to reset gsettings with:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
```

and just in case it makes a difference, which I can only imagine it won't, I slightly changed the file to:

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="gb"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS="ctrl:lctrl_meta,caps:ctrl_modifier"

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

(swapping the order of the options)

After restarting, the keys were bound correctly. Here is what gsettings reports after the restart:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
['ctrl:lctrl_meta', 'caps:ctrl_modifier']
```

Strangely the `ex-caps-lock-key` doesn't fully work as control as when I try to close a terminal tab with `ex-caps-lock-key + shift + w` it doesn't do anything, but it works for everything else.