# Set XKB options in my keyboard layout?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, layout

I used to use Debian and to use a keyboard layout with some Xkb options I edited the **/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-keyboard.conf** file like this:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "system-keyboard"
        MatchIsKeyboard "on"
        Option "XkbLayout" "us"
        Option "XkbModel" "pc105"
        Option "XkbVariant" "altgr-intl"
    Option "XkbOptions" "ctrl:ralt_rctrl,lv3:menu_switch"
EndSection
```

How can I do this with Ubuntu? I know how to change the layout using the GUI but that's all.

Also, can this be made so it's user-based? Only for one user.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: What release of Ubuntu?   (and the release of debian may also be useful, ie. difference in software stack ages)

Comment: @guiverc I was using the latest Debian unstable (although I think this works for every Debian system I've tried in the last couple of years). And my Ubuntu version is Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/950020/setting-multiple-options-in-etc-default-keyboard

Comment: @nobody Thanks but this is not a per-user configuration though.